# how to add rel attribute in insertlink popup of tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to know how to add rel attribute in insertlink popup of tinymce editor.

here is a link showing only four attributes in popup 
1 URL
2 Text to display
3 Title
4 Target

i want rel attribute also to be in popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link plugin has a configuration option to address this:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/#rel_list

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    rel_list: [
            {title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox'},
            {title: 'Table of contents', value: 'toc'}
    ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: can you please provide a link of demo of this.